# Android Studio - How to get Firebase URL from google-services.json? Cause when I open the google-services.json, there's no code for firebase URL

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my first time using Firebase, I just learn something from youtube and the tutorial said that I have to copy my Firebase URL at google-services.json. But when I open it, there's no any code that refer to Firebase URL

[This is mine google-services.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWUuQ.jpg)

[This is tutorial video that I watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Sjf.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say firebase url?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Here's the official Google documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @SABANTO I already edit the question, can you take a look?

Comment: @RazvanS. alright, i will check it out. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think you have to copy the URL code from your Google Firebase real time database, and not from json file. You have to copy from your project through the path:

google firebase -> Your Project -> Realtime Database -> data -> https link (https://fir-model (...))

And your have to copy it and paste in:

```
mR = new Firebase("paste URL");
```

Previously you should have declared a variable mR, for example:

```
private Firebase mR;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at how to connect your android studio project with firebase, you can follow this documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup/).

It is quite simple to connect your project to firebase directly without the need to copy-paste URLs with android studio. Also, the URL which you are looking for might be generated once you connect with firebase.